Liar's paradox, dialethism and law of excluded-middle
I've been reading about liar's paradox and its responses. I like Graham Priest, fantastic philospher and proponent of dialethism.
Graham argues that liar's paradox is solved by claiming that statement: "This statement is false" is both true and false. In another words, there are true contradictions. He argues that law of non-contradiction doesn't always hold bringing about new logical system called paraconsistent logic. This logical system had more success and popularity in ancient India. It was known as tetralema and used by Nagarjuna (Buddhist philospher and founder of Madhyamaka philosophical school).
Tetralema means that statement can be either true, false, both or neither (four options). In the classical logic (Aristotle), latter two options were not considered to be true (law of non-contradiction and excluded middle).
To me, it seems that liar's paradox can be solved by saying that statement is neither true or false. Not all statements can be prescribed truth value. They simply don't have this value. It's like trying to ascribe radius to a cube.
This brings me to the point where both dialethism and the other option are solutions to the paradox.
What are your views?

The idea that the liar paradox sentence is neither true nor false is one of the most common proposals. There have been many questions on the paradox, e.g. this one, and there is an article on it in the Stanford Encyclopedia that summarises the most common responses.

I'd agree with that solution.

A sentence is a sequence of words.
x is a proposition iff (x is true or x is false) and not (x is true and x is false)
A statement is a sentence that symbolizes a proposition.
Consider the following sentence:
This sentence symbolizes a false proposition.
To the untrained mind, if it's true then it's false, and if it's false then it's true. Hence it appears to be a paradox.  Let the sentence be S, so S=S symbolizes a false proposition.  Assume S is a statement [OSC1].  Represent the current truth value of the proposition symbolized by S as |S|.
Suppose |S|=1 [OSC2]. Then by Alfred Tarski's truth schema, S symbolizes a false proposition.  Therefore |S|=0.  Thus 1=|S| and |S|=0, so by transitivity of equality 1=0.  But we can prove not(1=0) as follows.  Suppose true=false.  Then x is a proposition iff (x is true or x is true) and not (x is true and x is true).  By the propositional calculus, theorems tautology 1, and tautology 2,
x is a proposition iff x is true and not(x is true)
Thus, there are no propositions, to avoid contradiction.  But there are propositions, so the only conclusion is not(true=false), i.e. not (1=0).  Thus, there are at least two truth values.
Hence, by conjunction, 1=0 and not(1=0), an explicit contradiction.  Therefore if |S|=1 then contradiction [CSC2]. Therefore, by reductio ad absurdum, not(|S|=1).
But we can prove|A|=1 or |A|=0, where A is an arbitrary statement.
One interpretation of 'reality' is the current moment in time.
Axioms of reality

If a statement describes reality then the current truth value of the proposition it denotes is true.
If a statement does not describe reality then the current truth value of the proposition it denotes is false.

Using the expression|A| for the current truth value of the proposition symbolized by A, we have:

If 'A' describes reality then |A|=1.
If 'A' doesn't describe reality then|A|=0.

By the law of the excluded middle, A describes reality or A does not describe reality. Thus by constructive dilemma |A|=1 or |A|=0.  Therefore there are at most two truth values. And since we proved that there are at least two truth values, there are exactly two truth values.
Thus |S|=1 or |S|=0, and not(S=1), therefore by disjunctive syllogism |S|=0.  Hence, S symbolizes a false proposition.  Therefore, |S|=1.  Again 1=|S| and |S|=0, so that 1=0.  But not (1=0).  Thus, 1=0 and not (1=0).  Thus, if S is a statement then contradiction [CSC1]. Therefore S isn't a statement so there is no proposition we have been reasoning about, the sentence is nonsense, so there is no paradox.

To me, it seems that liar's paradox can be solved by saying that statement is neither true or false. Not all statements can be prescribed truth value. They simply don't have this value. It's like trying to ascribe radius to a cube.

All propositions have truth value.  In the case of the liar's paradox the sentence doesn't symbolize a proposition, so it's not a statement.
